# append xml tag with python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to update xml file with new child tag within parent tag.
My base xml file is as such. Now I want to append element tag within sqlscript tag, update count of each added element tag and update total count in sqlscript tag with python script.

```
<?xml version=....>
<containers>
    <container name="abc">
       <emailNotifaction></emailNotifaction>
       <pythonScripts type="pythonScripts" count=0> </pythonScripts>
    </container>
<containers>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version=....>
<containers>
  <container name="abc">
   <emailNotifaction></emailNotifaction>
   <pythonScripts type="pythonScripts" count=2>
       <element index="1">
         <script>Text1</script>
         <ignoreError>True</ignoreError>
       <element>
       <element index="2">
         <script>Text2</script>
         <ignoreError>True</ignoreError>
       <element>
   </pythonScripts>
 </container>
<containers>
```

I found similar post and tried:

```
def SubElementWithText(parent, tag, text):
    attrib = {}
    element = parent.makeelement(tag, attrib)
    parent.append(element)
    element.text = text
    return element


tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

pythonScripts  = root.find('pythonscripts ')
element = ET.SubElement(pythonScripts, 'element ')
script = SubElementWithText(element, 'script', 'Text2')
```

However I get an error:

```
TypeError: subElement() argument 1 must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not None
```

Comment: It is better to use XSLT transformation for such tasks

Answer (score 1):

Using only ElementTree:

```
items = {'text1':'true', 'text2': 'false'}

#locate the insertion point
destination = root.find('.//pythonScripts')

for k in items.keys():
    ind = list(items).index(k)+1

    #create your new element as a string using f-strings
    elem_str = f'<element index="{ind}"><script>{k}</script><ignoreError>{items[k]}</ignoreError></element>'

    #import it into the DOM
    new_elem = ET.fromstring(elem_str)

    #insert the new element in its designated location
    destination.insert(1,new_elem)

    #update the counter count
    destination.set('count', str(len(items)))
#prettify
ET.indent(root, space="  ")
print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

Output should be your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is XSLT based solution.

The input XML was not well-formed. I had to fix it first.

The XSLT is following a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<containers>
    <container name="abc">
        <emailNotifaction></emailNotifaction>
        <pythonScripts type="pythonScripts" count="0"></pythonScripts>
    </container>
</containers>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pythonScripts">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@type"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="count">2</xsl:attribute>
            <element index="1">
                <script>Text1</script>
                <ignoreError>True</ignoreError>
            </element>
            <element index="2">
                <script>Text2</script>
                <ignoreError>True</ignoreError>
            </element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<containers>
  <container name="abc">
    <emailNotifaction/>
    <pythonScripts type="pythonScripts" count="2">
      <element index="1">
        <script>Text1</script>
        <ignoreError>True</ignoreError>
      </element>
      <element index="2">
        <script>Text2</script>
        <ignoreError>True</ignoreError>
      </element>
    </pythonScripts>
  </container>
</containers>
```